# Get user's events with Firebase (many to many relationship)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm a Front-End Developer and for the first-time, I'm using Firebase to build an application. I read some documentation/articles and watched this interesting video about foreign keys (many to many relationship): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ran_Ylug7AE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=2.

I'm trying to apply this approach to retrieve events for a specific user. Ideally, I want to get this information without requesting/paying for too much data. First, this is how I set-up the following database structure (see video):

```
{
  users:
    "abc": {
      firstname: "Maxime",
      ...
    },
    "def": {
      firstname: "John",
      ...
    },
  },
  events: {
    "eventAbc-": {
      title: "Some great event",
      ...
    },
    "eventDef": {
      title: "Another great event",
      ...
    } 
  },
  eventAttendees: {
    "eventAbc": {
      abc: true,
      def: true,
    },
    "eventDef": {
      abc: true,
    } 
  }
}
```

To get user's events, I have the following which actually works:

```
getEvents(userId) {
  const self = this;
  const query = firebase.firestore().collection('eventAttendees');
  var promises = [];
  query.onSnapshot(function(snap) {
    snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
      const data = doc.data();
      if (data[userId]) {
        // user has been invited to this event
        promises.push(self.getEvent(doc.id));
      }
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
      console.log("All events");
      console.log(results);
    });
  });
}

getEvent(eventId) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const query = firebase.firestore()
    .collection('events')
    .doc(eventId);
    query.onSnapshot(function(snap) {
      resolve(snap.data());
    });
  });
}

getEvents('abc');
```

**Questions**

1. I don't think/know if I have the right and optimized approach? Any documentation/Github project I should look into as reference?
2. What does happen if 'abc' has been invited to 1 million events? I feel, I'm looping and need to handle pagination out of the box. Is there a better way?
3. Let's assume, each event has a lot of information (details). However, on the homepage, I just need to display main information (event title, event date). Where should I store that to avoid loading a lot of information.

Hopefully, there is someone who can find the time to reply to my questions. 
**Thanks**.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be watching David's great video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s), which was written for the Firebase Realtime Database. Since your code uses the Cloud Firestore API, I'd recommend switching over to Todd's [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) series, which contains similar information and much more, but then tailored towards Firestore.

> What does happen if 'abc' has been invited to 1 million events?

No user is ever going to watch those million events. So don't load them. Think of how many items a user will realistically see, and then load those. Typically this will be one or a few screenfuls. If you think they may want to load more, allow them to load a new page. Search firebase and pagination to see many questions about that topic.

> Let's assume, each event has a lot of information (details). However, on the homepage, I just need to display main information (event title, event date). Where should I store that to avoid loading a lot of information.

You should only load the data you need. If you need a subset of the data for each event in the initial list view, create a separate node or collection with just that information for each event. Yes, you're indeed duplicating data that way, but that is quite normal in NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking the time to reply to my questions. Indeed, I like this video series and I'm looking forward to watch the one you've recommended which seems to be more recent.

I agree with you and definitely want to load only what's needed. At the moment, I don't have much datas so it's difficult for me to conceive/anticipate that. I should have probably taken advantage of .limit(10) or .startAt() in the function getEvents?

I'm not familiar with database in general and don't really know where I should have a subset of the data for each event? Is the following what you would call initial list view? For my example, is it the right place? If not, where would put that?

```
eventAttendees: {
  "eventAbc": {
    title: "Some great event",
    eventDate: "",
    moreKeyInformation: "",
    abc: true,
    def: true,
  },
  "eventDef": {
    title: "Another great event",
    eventDate: "",
    moreKeyInformation: "",
    abc: true,
  } 
}
```